# Langton's ant algorithm using AnglePath

Tags: algorithm, cellular-automata

I would like to implement [Langton's ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) algorithm using [AnglePath](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html). I know there are some MMA implementation on the internet but I would like to implement it myself.

Here is definition of algorithm:

- At a white square, turn 90° right, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit
- At a black square, turn 90° left, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit

Here is my try.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mat = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
pos = {5, 5};
s = Table[

   seq = Sequence @@ pos;
   Which[

        mat[[seq]] == 0, {pos = Last@AnglePath[pos, {90 \[Degree]}], 
     mat[[seq]] = 1},
         mat[[seq]] == 1, {pos = Last@AnglePath[pos, {-90 \[Degree]}],
      mat[[seq]] = 0}

    ]; mat , 6];

ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {True, True}, 
   DataReversed -> True] & /@ s
```

[image]

It seems issue is pos; Observe that

```
AnglePath[{5, 5}, {90 \[Degree], 90 \[Degree], 90 \[Degree]}]
```

> {{5, 5}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}}

and

```
AnglePath[#, {90 \[Degree]}] & /@ {{5, 5}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}, {4, 5}}
```

> {{{5, 5}, {5, 6}}, {{5, 6}, {5, 7}}, {{4, 6}, {4, 7}}, {{4, 5}, {4, 
>      6}}}

I need `pos=Last@AnglePath` in the first iteration and `pos=First@AnglePath` in the rest of iteration I guess?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant#Mathematica I found it really enlightening but without `AnglePath`

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, but it is hard digest for me. Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to remember current orientation of the ant:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mat = ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}];
pos = {50, 50, -90 °};
s = Table[
   seq = Sequence @@ Most@pos;
   Which[
    mat[[seq]] == 0, {pos = Flatten@Last@AnglePath[Most@pos, {Last@pos + 90 °}, {"Position", "FrameAngle"}], mat[[seq]] = 1}
    , mat[[seq]] == 1, {pos = Flatten@Last@AnglePath[Most@pos, {Last@pos - 90°}, {"Position", "FrameAngle"}], mat[[seq]] = 0}
    ];
   mat
   , 11000
   ];

ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {True, True}, 
   DataReversed -> True] &[Last@s]
```

[image: Langton's ant path]

Comment: Oh I see, it is beautiful, thanks..